# Why tabbar is hidden on navigation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have created a tab bar application,
There is a present modal view controller when button clicked in viewcontroller 1, and with navigation controller i can navigate to Viewcontroller2 from modal view
My problem is that,when i navigated to viewController2 the tab bar is hidden,how can i show the tab bar?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of what you are talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly, but are you asking why your tab bar is hidden when you present a new view controller modally?

Comment: Is viewController2 presented as a modal view controller?

Comment: You cannot have the tab bar while you present a modal view controller. When you present a new modal view , you will create a new navigation controller for that modal view. Because In modal view controllers, you cannot access previous view controller's navigation controller in default.

Comment: No actually..i have presented a modal view in ViewController1, Let it say "ModalView", From that i am navigating to ViewController2(not as modal presentation,but as uinavigation)
At that time i cannot see the tabbar(which was already there at first time)

Jishi KP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're pushing a view controller onto your navigation controller's stack, then the tab bar will stay:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

But if you're presenting it as a modal view controller then it becomes the top/front-most view (presented in full screen), thus hiding the tab bar until the view controller is dismissed:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The point of a modal view controller is to force the user to deal with the presented view controller before doing anything else inside the app. If you need to access `viewController1` in `viewController2` then you could declare a property `viewController1 *previousViewController` in `viewController2` and set `viewController2.previousViewController = self;` (in `viewController1`) before presenting the view controller. Alternatively you could try adding the view (subtracting the height of the tab bar when defining the frame) to your tab bar controller's view.